# numpy python 3.4 for beginners

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am a beginner in programming.

I installed anaconda on my laptop in order to get numpy. After that I load the npy files as follows:

```
import numpy
X_train = numpy.load("train-features.npy")
X_test = numpy.load("test-features.npy")
```

Now I would like to see what there is inside them. So i tried to print them but it gives me a memory error.

How can I look into these file in order to understand how my data set looks like?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error message you get? This might give further clues as to the exact problem you're having.

Comment: Please show us the exact stack trace you receive

Comment: Yes sure :) It highlits this string of code: array = numpy.fromfile(fp, dtype=dtype, count=count) and it says to me: MemoryError. I think that I have don't have enough space in my computer because the file it's really big. I also tried to run it in jupyter but it crashes when I tried to upload the data.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing details or error, I am assuming that you may be getting memory error due to memory buffer getting overwhelmed because of large size of your data.
If that is the case, then you may want to memory map the npy / dat file to a disk.

Detailed examples are available at [scipy.org numpy.load page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.load.html)
and details about numpy.memmap are available [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html#numpy.memmap)

If you can post error and provide more insight into data that may help one with determining correct cause of the problem.

Comment: It highlits this string of code: array = numpy.fromfile(fp, dtype=dtype, count=count) and it says to me: MemoryError. I think that I have don't have enough space in my computer because the file it's really big. I also tried to run it in jupyter but it crashes when I tried to upload the data. Thank you for your answer I will read this info that you suggested me :)

Comment: Since you have resource constraints, you may want to try out options suggested in my answer. Loading data to disk may alleviate memory  overload. Also, even after loading from disk, try to load data in chunks that your server can handle. And if you are satisfied with answer, do accept answer to close the Q/A loop.

Comment: It's possible that maybe PyScripter that I am using doesn't have enough memory? Do you know if there is some other shells with a bigger memory that I can use? Because I also read something about creating a temporary directory but I don't know once I create it how to put my npy data files in the temporary directory.

Comment: If you can put more relevant code on SO i may be able to provide help to  create temp dir and transfer data files to those dir within python code. I use IDLE , you are welcome to try it out.